# NM_KILLFOCUS of a CEdit box is called twice

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a CPropertyPage upon which I have a few edit boxes saved and most notably a CPropertySheet based tab control, this is controlled by a class called `CMainPage`. This CPropertySheet tab control consists out of 6 identical CPropertyPages, which are shown depending on whether certain checkboxes are ticked or not. These subsequent pages are controlled by a separate class called `CPage`.

On these pages, I have a bunch of CEdit boxes where I write some data. I want this data to be stored somehow, without the user having to perform some action (such as continuously clicking a save button).

So far, I've managed to capture the `NM_KILLFOCUS` message by using the `ON_NOTIFY` macro. I then store this data in a struct which belongs to the `CPage` class. This struct is then sent to the `CMainPage` class, which handles it and stores the data in an .xml file.

It looks like this (only showing relevant functions):

CMainPage.h:

```
CPage::TPageData m_PageData[6];
CPage _page[6];

void SetPageData(int nPageId, CPage::TPageData::pageData);
```

CMainPage.cpp:

```
CMainPage::CMainPage()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        _page[i].InitUI(this);
        _page[i].SetPageId(i);
    }
}

void
CMainPage::SetPageData(int nPageId, CPage::TPageData pageData)
{
    if( strlen(pageData.Edit1) > 0)
        m_PageData[nPageId].Edit1 = pageData.Edit1

    if( strlen(pageData.Edit2) > 0)
        m_PageData[nPageId].Edit2 = pageData.Edit2
}
```

CPage.h:

```
struct TPageData {
    CString Edit1,
    CString Edit2;
};

afx_msg void OnKillFocus(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult);
void InitUI(CWnd* pVME);
void SetPageId(int n);

TPageData  m_PageData;
int        m_PageId;
CMainPage* m_pMainPage;
```

CPage.cpp:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(Page, CPropertyPage)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_KILLFOCUS, IDC_EDIT1, &Page::OnKillFocus)
    ON_NOTIFY(NM_KILLFOCUS, IDC_EDIT2, &Page::OnKillFocus)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// Called during initialization of each CPage object.
void
CPage::InitUI(CWnd* pVME)
{
    m_pMainPage = reinterpret_cast<CMainPage *>( pVME);
}

void
CPage::SetPageId(int n)
{
    m_PageId = n;
}

void
Page::OnKillFocus(NMHDR *pNMHDR, LRESULT *pResult)
{
    // Get text from edit box
    CString Str;
    GetDlgItem(pNMHDR->idFrom)->GetWindowText(Str);

    switch(pNMHDR->idFrom)
    {
    case IDC_EDIT1:
        {
            m_PageData.Edit1 = Str;
            m_pMainPage->SetPageData(m_PageId, m_PageData);
            break;
        }
    case IDC_EDIT2:
        {
            m_PageData.Edit2 = Str;
            m_pMainPage->SetPageData(m_PageId, m_PageData);
            break;
        }
    }
    *pResult = 1;
}
```

The problem I have now, is that the `NM_KILLFOCUS` message is called twice, which means `OnKillFocus()` is called twice. It gets called even more often when I switch between different tabs. I can't figure out what is causing it, does anybody have any suggestions?

EDIT: In the past I solved this by capturing the `NM_RETURN` message. This meant the user had to hit the Enter key after completing the input. However, the user got quickly annoyed by this solution and asked me to solve it in a different, hence the question.

As of now, I transfer all of the data from the individual `CPage`'s to one array of 'TPageData' structs. Once the user is satisfied that all the data is transferred to the array, the user hits save and then all the data from this array is parsed to the disk. When loading the data, it's all done in reverse.

Solved using `EN_CHANGE`! See here:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CPage, CPropertyPage)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CPage::OnEnChange)
    ON_EN_CHANGE(IDC_EDIT1, &CPage::OnEnChange)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

void
CPage::OnEnChange()
{
    CString Str;

    CWnd* pWnd = GetFocus();
    int iControlID = pWnd->GetDlgCtrlID();
    CEdit* pEditCtrl = (CEdit*)(pWnd);
    pEditCtrl->GetWindowText(Str);

    switch(iControlID)
    {
    case IDC_EDIT1:
        {
             m_PageData.Edit1 = Str;
             m_pMainPage->SetPageData(m_PageId, m_PageData);
             break;
        }
    case IDC_EDIT2:
        {
             m_PageData.Edit1 = Str;
             m_pMainPage->SetPageData(m_PageId, m_PageData);
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: [EN_CHANGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/controls/en-change) is arguably a better place to sync user input with your backing store. You should probably also consider using the [dialog data exchange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/dialog-data-exchange) infrastructure instead of rolling your own.

Comment: @iinspectable that might be too much saving in some scenarios (eg. user typing - or simply a too slow connection)

Comment: Maybe, maybe not. If you want confidence, measure. But that totally gives reason to the question: Why does the OP want those intermittent changes to begin with? I cannot think of any good reason to do that, irrespective of which message you pick to perform the store.

Comment: @darune if EN_CHANGE is used, the store could be done at most once every x seconds and not on each EN_CHANGE

Comment: The idea is that a user enters the required data depending on how many tabs are active. Once the user is satisfied that all the data is entered in correctly, the user can hit a save button where all the data is then stored to the disk. The previous solution I had was to capture the Enter key, so the user had to hit enter after each edit field, but of course the user got quickly annoyed and asked if it can be solved in another way. I'll edit my post to reflect this.

Comment: @IInspectable what do  you mean with using the DDX? I use the DDX to initialize all of my edit boxes, but how would I use the DDX to retrieve the data from the edit boxes?

Comment: [UpdateData](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#updatedata) has a parameter, that controls the direction. If `bSaveAndValidate` is `FALSE`, data is moved from bound variables *to* the controls, if it is `TRUE`, data is moved *from* the controls to the bound variables. That's explained in the article I linked to in my first comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not perhaps the answer you are looking for but a few things springs to mind:

1. You could check if buffer is modified (eg. by storing a
   hash of the buffer) See: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/hash.
2. Instead of KillFocus event, you could use the idle loop to
   check+save in. This might be a more suitable time to autosave. See:
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwinapp-class?view=vs-2019#onidle

Comment: Idle processing may not run, leaving you with incomplete/inconsistent data. That's not a reliable solution. Hashing the data is only possible, once you have transferred it from the controls. The question is asking about doing just that, and DDX is the answer.

Comment: @IInspectable If OP wan't to sync after every change then do that instead. I suggested idle processing as a response to the OP using killfocus (and yes you *can* starve idle - but that only happends as a result of user input in my experience - so in practice its not an issue).

Comment: If code can fail, it *will* fail. And this is really just recommending a poor implementation of a needless workaround. The OP wants to use dialog data exchange (DDX), and simply doesn't understand, that everything is implemented for them already. They just need to trigger it.

Comment: I usually steer far away from DDX as it is kind of obscuring and not needed in generel.

Comment: DDX serves as the adapter between MFC's object model and Windows' native control implementations. You construct an MFC dialog instance, and feed data into its class members. On display, member contents are forwarded to the native controls. As long as the dialog is displayed, the entire state is stored in the native controls. When dismissed, DDX moves the control contents back into class members, ready for the application to pick up. I cannot envision a single use case, where *not* using DDX would be a solution. If you feel that it were not needed, chances are that you are replicating it.

Comment: Getting a value from a control - can hardly be called 'replicating'. I'd much rather have that than all the unchecked casting, etc. going on with DDX.

Comment: This amounts to writing code, needlessly, replicating existing functionality. To employ DDX, all that is required is a single line in the [DoDataExchange](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cwnd-class#dodataexchange) override. Everything else works out-of-the-box. And it works seamlessly with the dialog wizard, too. The *"unchecked casting[s]"* are a non-issue. The implementation is type-safe at the interface, like any other C++ library. I'm sure you wouldn't dismiss `std::vector` based on the observation, that it uses unchecked casts in its implementation, now would you?

Comment: `std::vector` doesn't use unchecked casts - that would make for example core checker fail if setup to check that since it's a template.

Comment: There is more than one implementation of `std::vector`. And static code analyzers generally exclude code that is part of the library implementation. Regardless, you wouldn't dismiss `CString` based on the observation, that it uses unchecked casts in its implementation, now would you?